# Oracle display number of unique values for column combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | A3 |
| B1 | B2 | B3 |
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| C1 | C4 | C3 |

For each unique combination of C1 and C3, I would like to keep the first value in C2, but storing the count of unique elements in C2 (for the mentioned combination C1, C3). I would expect the below result:

| O1 | O2 | O3 | O4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | A3 | 1 |
| B1 | B2 | B3 | 1 |
| C1 | C2 | C3 | 2 |

Comment: Please define "first value".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results set in Oracle are unordered so asking for the first `C2` row does not make sense unless you have some way of defining how to get the first. If you just want the minimum value then:

```sql
SELECT c1 AS o1,
       MIN( c2 ) AS o2,
       c3 As o3,
       COUNT(*) As o4
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       c1,
       c3;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( C1, C2, C3 ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 'B2', 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 'C2', 'C3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 'C4', 'C3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> O1 | O2 | O3 | O4
> :- | :- | :- | -:
> A1 | A2 | A3 |  1
> C1 | C2 | C3 |  2
> B1 | B2 | B3 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b434088a55585f7d5ab6b1ef5dd9764)*